# What happens to the console input while a process is running?

Tags: unix, terminal

If for example I run a command from the terminal like this:

```
$ find . | xargs grep something
```

The terminal then goes in a sort of pending state and I can type in characters and whatnot as I wait for the command to start printing stuff to stdout.

What happens with that input? Is it saved somewhere, does it do anything at all? I know I can use it to pass signals to the application (such as SIGINT by way of typing in ^C) but what about some other input? I'm referring specifically to the cases where the application is not prompting the user for input.

Thanks and apologies if this is a bit obvious.

Comment: Just a word of caution: `find` and `xargs` are better used with `find … -print0 | xargs -0` to overcome issues with spaces or newlines in file names. You'll find that your command won't work for a file called, let's say "foo bar".

Comment: Thanks for that, normally on our environment very seldom would a file have a space in it but it's a good habit to start calling it like you've suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other input is saved in a buffer and is used for the next command in the shell.

Comment: Sorry, does this mean that while the process executes any rubbish I've typed in (e.g. asdasdekhef) will be passed on to the next command?

Comment: As John says, the text you paste/write is taken to be a command and is executed once the running process ends. This is very handy when pasting a long list of commands into a terminal since they will be run sequentially.

Comment: I weep for the future.